# Correctly handle zero-width entities adjacent to code-formatted text

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Particularly in syntax templates, placeholders are conventionally represented with italics and subscripts, and white space can be significant.  Without zero-width entities it's not possible to correctly render such examples:

```
> `doit --separator=`_`character`<sub>`opt`</sub>_
```

renders as

> `doit --separator=`*`character`<sub>`opt`</sub>*
>                                                            ^                   ^

The first marked space is simply wrong, the second is just annoying.

So, please implement `&zwj` and `&zwnj`

```
> `doit --separator=`_&zwj;`character`&zwj;<sub>`opt`</sub>_
```

to enable rendering that correctly?

Comment: From the source, it doesn't look like there should even be a space there. If you copy and paste it would not have extra spaces. Is it cause of the formatting that causes the renderer to space things out?

Comment: @MxyL I don't know.  I also think the space shouldn't be rendering, but whitespace being significant I also think fixing it would be a bit fraught.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this kindly explain?  I couldn't and can't  find any kind of dup, nor can I see how this is off-topic or otherwise out of place here, nor can I see any way to quote relevant material from language standards without this.  Not being a fan of wasting people's time, I'd like to learn how to avoid it here.

Comment: @MxyL I don't understand what you mean about the c&p - I can't find any way to make it render without that space.

Comment: @jthill Voting on meta is for agreement or disagreement (and doesn't affect your rep). Maybe someone thinks it's not a big deal and doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: @jthill I mean if someone were to copy the syntax and paste it into their editor those spaces wouldn't be there. It's purely a rendering thing. If you slowly highlight over it you'll see that the `c` is just a bit weird. But I understand what you mean, if I were typing it out myself while following what you wrote I'd assume there's a space cause...it looks like there's a space! I guess your suggestion for adding a zero-width character is to forcefully get rid of the weird things, but I'm not sure if that would solve the problem either.

Comment: I'm confused about the use of zero width joiner here, Wikipedia tells me the zero width joiner is used for rendering merged versions of character pairs in script like arabic. e.g. turning क ् into क्‍. It seems like you just want to get rid of the 5px horizontal padding on code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're gonna get that fancy, just use HTML for the whole thing:

```html
<pre><code>doit --separator=<i>character<sub>opt</sub></i></code></pre>
```

...which produces:

```
doit --separator=characteropt
```

Comment: Right.  I see that GitHub renders the same as SO, though I don't see how md gets anything but that HTML from that source.  No matter, this does exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: As @OGHaza points out, the root cause is that you have *separate* code blocks and they each have their own horizontal padding.